# Grub menu appears on top of grub customizer menu and background image

Tags: boot, grub2, customizer

Starting today, on top of a fully up-to-date version of 17.10 and Grub Customizer, when booting, first the background image and colored menu as set in Grub Customizer appears and then immediately, the grub menu appears as it would without Grub Customizer, but only occupying the upper left eighth of the screen.  The menu still works correctly, so it's only a cosmetic issue. I could just delete Grub Customizer but I have grown accustomed to my splash screen at bootup and would like to retain it.

Comment: I believe grub customizer normally adds its grub scripts and copies standard grub files to a sub-directoy. It would then seem like you may still have both sets of files? Loot at these files and which are executable. `ll /etc/grub.d` Perhaps a grub update added standard files back in?

Comment: I checked and none of the back upped files (in /etc/grub.d/ backup/etc_grub_d) were executable.  Comparing the changes (many of them) between the files in /etc/grub.d and  /etc/grub.d/ backup/etc_grub_d leads me to suspect that somewhere the menu is displayed twice but I can't figure out where it's happening yet.

Comment: I think that my problem dates back to a failed Windows 10 update (I dual boot Win 10 and Ubuntu) because of the problem the Fall Creators Update had with my wireless card. I have since removed the unneeded card and fixed the spurious Windows 7 boot loader problem left over from the original Windows 7 installation.  After running Boot Repair and update-grub I have a clean working Grub menu, but I still have the problem of superimposed images, now on top of each other since I removed my splash screen.

Comment: Perhaps related? https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1752767 or https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1748028

Comment: This is probably related to those bugs.  What I have is both the console output displayed on top of the graphical output. I uncommented the the line  GRUB_TERMINAL-console in /etc/default/grub and ran upgrade-grub and the menu was displayed as expected.